# Passing data from controller to model in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller where I get the value from the hbs, which sends me the selected country value. I need this selected country in the model to compute and return back some results back to the hbs. How set this value in controller and get it in the model so I can compute using that value?

Comment: Sample code will explain your problems more clear. I guess you are looking for computed property in controller to update model property

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be some different approaches to achieve this. However, I will give you some example which will hopefully help you.

```
 //Controller.js
notes: Ember.computed('model.notes.[]', 'model.notes.@each.date', function() {
   return this.get('model.notes').sortBy('date').reverse();  //This is an example of Computed function which in this case it's sorting notes based on date. 
}),
 blink: null,
  actions: {
    taskChangeColor: function() {
      this.set('blink', 'blinker'); // this is another example that set new data by action which can be retrive from model and set to property 
    }
  }
```

or another thing that you can do is to use Computed function in Model itself like

```
 // model.js which is using ember-data and moment
  timeZone: DS.attr(),  //for example one property coming from server
  utcOffsetFormat: Ember.computed(function() {
    let time = moment.tz(this.get('timeZone')).format('hh:mm a');
    return time;
   // using a computed function to instantiate another value based on existing model property which means you can simpley use this property instead of direct one.
  })
```

Additionally, you still are eligible to use action in Route.js instead of controller an example would be :

```
 //route.js
 actions: {
    changeSave: function(step) {
      var something = {
        contact: this.currentModel,
      };
      this.currentModel.set('step', something.contact);
      this.currentModel.save().then(d => {
       // set your alert or whatever for success promise
        return d;
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(error(e.message));
        return e;
      });
    },
```

in above example you can see that I have set an action to save notes in model which easily can set() to the model with exact same property name and if you do this you will get the result back immediately in your view.

hope it can help you. I recommend to read [Ember-Docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/controllers/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, for your requirement you don't need controller properties for selectedCountryValue. You can keep this value in model itself.

In route,

```
setupController(model,transition){
   this._super(...arguments); //this will set model property in controller.
   Ember.set(model,'selectedCountryValue','US'); //you can set default value
}
```

and inside controller, you create computed property with dependent on model.selectedCountryValue. and compute some results

```
result:Ember.Computed('model.selectedCountryValue',function(){
//compute something return the result
}
```

In template, you can use `{{model.selectedCountryValue}}` directly.